# Updating Many-to-Many relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have 3 models (simplified):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='products', to_field='category_name')
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', related_name='products', to_field='brand_name')

class Brand(models.Model):    
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='categories')

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I want to change a Category in admin to a bunch of products, i have a custom admin function written for that. After that I need to update `Brand-Categories` Many-to-Many relation to check if that `Category` is still available for a specific `Brand`. I have written this function:

```
def brand_refresh():
    brands = Brand.objects.all().prefetch_related('shops', 'categories')
    products = Product.objects.select_related('shop', 'brand', 'category')

    for brand in list(brands):
        for category in brand.categories.all():
            if not products.filter(category=category).exists():
                brand.categories.remove(category)

               for product in list(products.filter(brand=brand).distinct('category')):
                    if product.category not in [None, category]:
                        brand.categories.add(product.category)
```

Seems to me this monstro is working, but it takes 2 hours to loop over all cycles (i have ~220k products, 4k+ brands, and ~500 categories). **I there any better way to update M2M relation here?** I think `.prefetch_related()` should help here, but what I have now seems have no effect.

Comment: Perhaps this will help a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839115/django-removing-item-from-many-to-many-relation-more-efficiently

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for the first part of your loop:

You should try this on a disposable local copy of your database and check that everything works well before running these in production:

```
from django.db.models import Count

# get a list of all categories which have no products
empty_categories = Category.objects.annotate(product_count=Count('products')).filter(product_count=0).values_list('id', flat=True)

# delete association of empty categories in all brands
Brand.categories.through.objects.filter(category_id__in=list(empty_categories)).delete()
```

For the second part, perhaps you can do something like this, though I'm not convinced if it's any faster (or even correct as it is):

```
for brand in Brand.objects.all():
    # get a list of categories of all products in the brand
    brand_product_categories = brand.products.all().value_list('category__id', flat=True).distinct()

    # get the brand's categories
    brand_categories = Category.objects.filter(category__brand=brand).value_list('id', flat=True)

    # get elements from a not in b
    categories_to_add = set(brand_product_categories) - set(brand_categories)

    for category_id in categories_to_add:
        brand.categories.add(category_id)
```

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty nice, I will test that. Only what - i think it is better to refactor that: `empty_categories = Category.objects.annotate(product_count=Count('products')).filter(product_count=0).values_list('category_id', flat=True)` and next use it `category_id__in = list(empty_categories)`. Any ideas about second part? :)

Comment: not sure, i've tried to come up with something, but i'd need to test it to see how much faster it is (if any)

Comment: added in your refactor in the first bit

Comment: yeah, I see. shouldn't there be `category_id__in=list(empty_categories)`? As I know it should be converted?

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll add that in too. Just empty_categories might work too, as I have a feeling there's some conversion to list going on in Django's code itself.

Comment: I have tested similar query without `list()` and it did not work. `empty_categories` is not a list, but some kind of `QuerySet` variation at that moment, not sure exactly. Thank you for your answer, I will test it and let you know if it is faster :)

Comment: Sure, please let me know. This will be an interesting experiment I suppose, especially the second part.

Comment: one more question - in `brand_categories = ... .value_list('id', flat=True)` *id* is *category_id*? Looks like in different queries you use different names of the same field? I have `category_id` and `brand_id` in my models btw.

Comment: if you're querying the Category model itself, you don't have to specify `category_id`, just `id` will do, I think.